# On OSX, how to get rid of the empty spaces between windows?

Tags: macos

On OSX, it seems impossible to fill the whole screen with applications. For some reason, OSX won't allow me to increase the size of the terminal further (notice the empty space below it) and the size of chrome further (notice the empty space on its left size). Is there any way to improve this behavior?

[image: bad]

Open the image directly to see it in full resolution and notice how terribly unadjusted the window is.

Comment: This is only related to Terminal. Other apps don't behave like this, in my quick tests.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Terminal.app will only expand in increments of one display line of text.  The gap you are seeing is because there is not enough space to increase the height by another line of text.

There is a third-party application, iTerm, which may behave differently but I haven't tried it.

Comment: You're right about Terminal's increments. (Even using http://spectacleapp.com, which allows for easy "Move to the left half" and more, you'll see that, though it then nicely centers the window to get even spacing on all sides.)